# Difference of the length according to dimension of the coordinate system

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, spacetime-dimensions

We know that the length of a vector does not depend on the coordinate system we choose. It's always the same. But is it still true when we add additional dimensions to our coordinate system? As long as logically we do not experience for example four or five dimension, which mathematics prove that the length is the same in all coordinate system with dimensions more than three?

Comment: Grab a book on mathematical physics and see Tensor Analysis. Here is an introduction to Tensor Analysis by NASA scientist: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/Numbers/Math/documents/Tensors_TM2002211716.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand you question, but I'll try to answer it. Let's assume we have an arbitrary number of dimensions $N$. Then the length of a vector in this $N$-dimensional space is given by the $L_2$-norm:
$$ \ell = \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2\right)^{1/2} , $$
where $a_n$ are the components of the vector.

If we actually had a smaller space, one with fewer dimensions, say $M<N$, then we would still have the same $L_2$-norm, but where the sum only runs to $M$. All the vectors in the smaller space have only (or at most) $M$ nonzero components.

Now we embed this smaller space into the original space with $N$-dimensions. In other words, we add $N-M$ dimensions. So we need to use the original $L_2$-norm with $N$ components, but because only $M$ of these components are nonzero, the expression for the length of the vectors would reduce to the one for the $M$-dimensional space. Hence, the length of the vectors remains the same even though we've added extra dimensions.